# Simplifying a fraction with radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

> Simplify the following fraction as much as possible
>   $$\def\A{\sqrt{15}}\def\B{\sqrt{35}}
> \frac{(8+2\A)^{3/2}+(8-2\A)^{3/2}}{(12+2\B)^{3/2}-(12-2\B)^{3/2}}
> $$

This problem is just driving me insane. I've tried so many different approaches but it keeps becoming a mess for me

I worked with conjugates but that won't help. The first step would be to get rid of the exponent.

Any help on this problem?

Comment: Have you tried first cubing the Radical Binomials and then square rooting them?

Comment: do you mean cubing them individually, for example taking $[(8+2\sqrt{15})^{3/2}]^3$

Comment: No. I mean first cubing $(8+2\sqrt{15})^3$ (spoiler alert - its really big, and you end up with two radical terms). Then you set $(a+b\sqrt{15})^2=(8+2\sqrt{15})^3$ and solve for $a$ and $b$ and do that or all the terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

- What is $\Big(\sqrt5 + \sqrt3\Big)^2$ and $\Big(\sqrt5 - \sqrt3\Big)^2$ ?
- What is $\Big(\sqrt7 + \sqrt5\Big)^2$ and $\Big(\sqrt7 - \sqrt5\Big)^2$ ?

Another hint:

Please find the following two formulas and use them.

1. $(a+b)^3 + (a-b)^3$
2. $(a+b)^3 - (a-b)^3$

Comment: well for 1. its $5+ 2\sqrt{15}+3=8+2\sqrt{15}$. I see, its the above equation but how did you get that?

Comment: If I tell you the following: The sum of two integers is 8 and the product is 15. Can you (mentally) find the integers?

Comment: Similarly, if I tell you the following: The sum of two integers is 12 and the product is 35. Can you (mentally) find the integers?

Answer (score 0):

For the nominator I get:
$$\sqrt{8+2\sqrt{15}}^3+\sqrt{8-2\sqrt{15}}^3 = 28\sqrt{5}$$
For the denominator I get:
$$\sqrt{12+2\sqrt{35}}^3-\sqrt{12-2\sqrt{35}}^3 = 52\sqrt{5}$$
So in the end I get:
$$\frac{28\sqrt{5}}{52\sqrt{5}} = \frac{7}{13}$$